# Responding to events while application is not in focus

Tags: windows-services, background-process

I am having trouble writing a program that I want to be active always.

I wrote code on keydown to do something, but when `form1` is minimized or in tray keydown event does not response.  How can I get my application to respond to keyboard events even when it is not in focus?

addition :

its window app , and lang is c#.NET ,

Comment: What language and libraries are you using?

Comment: I'm guessing the language is .NET because of the form1 reference in the question... duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526458/respond-to-keyboard-when-not-in-focus-c-vista

Answer (score 0):

If I can assume that this program is for Windows, you cannot do that. Once you application window is closed, it will not raise KeyUp/KeyDown. Nearest to what you want is either hotkeys (to activate program once specific key is detected) or keyboard hook (if you wish to have overview of every key press).

However, what you will use depends on which exact scenario were you thinking about.